# create trigger MySQL to update salary in employee table

Tags: mysql, plsql

how to create trigger MySQL to update salary in employee table and replacment old value in salary column to old_salary column?

Answer (score 0):

See [CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html):

```
create trigger salary_trigger
    before update on employee
    for each row begin
        if new.salary != old.salary then
            set new.old_salary = old.salary
        end if;
    end;
```